# SSH tunnel using libssh and c lang

Tags: c, ssh, ssh-tunnel, libssh

I am trying to use `libssh` to open an SSH tunnel.

Basically, I have two hosts in the way. First, I would need to SSH to the first one (I have already done this part), then I would need to SSH from that host to the second host:

```
[my PC] --SSH--> [host 1] --ssh--> [host 2]       (similar to ssh -L )
```

Is this possible in `libssh`?

I tried to use this function `ssh_channel_open_forward`, but this only opens a TCP session, not a ssh session.

Comment: did you manage to do it? care to share?

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the tutorial how to do port forwarding with libssh at http://api.libssh.org/stable/libssh_tutor_forwarding.html

Comment: it is a stub example that does not show how to actually do the forwarding stuffs. It only creates tunnel and that is it!

Comment: You can have a look at https://blog.monyog.com/how-to-integrating-ssh-tunneling-inside-your-application/ which is a bit more full-blown example.